# How to generate annotations and use lombok with javapoet?

Tags: java, lombok, javapoet

**Is there any way (and any sense) to use Lombok when I am using javapoet?**
Here is example:

```
TypeSpec typeSpec = TypeSpec
        .classBuilder("MyDtoWithLombok")
        .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
        //.addAnnotation(NoArgsConstructor.class)
        //.addAnnotation(AllArgsConstructor.class)
        //.addAnnotation(Data.class)
        //.addAnnotation(Builder.class)
        .addField(...)
        .build();
```

When I am trying to add Lombok annotation *(like that -> Data.class")* I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lombok/NoArgsConstructor
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lombok.NoArgsConstructor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Lombok is not on the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because Lombok is usually given provided scope - you ordinarily don't want it on the classpath, because it's supposed to be processed and removed at compile-time.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.20</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` line, or change it to `compile`. Both are equivalent, since `compile` is the default.

I would personally explicitly use `compile` and maybe even add a comment explaining why you're not using `provided`, since a casual reader might think it's a mistake otherwise, and maybe try to change it to `provided` again.

Comment: Well, what a great answer. Thank you very much for that and for your advices!

Comment: It resolved my issue, I already checked that.